# Fragments onResume() is calling, when coming from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to call onResume only when fragment resumed from recent Apps menu, not when frgment resumed from another activity??

I want to refresh my fragment only when it is resumed from Recent Apps menu., But when i call OnResume inside fragment, it is calling when fragment is loaded from another activity. How can i prevent this?

Comment: You can't.  That's what's supposed to happen.  You need some other argument to prevent this.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Typically, the it's best for a Fragment to *not* know how it's being started.  That way you can prepare for all cases.  I think the question would be, what are you trying to accomplish by going against convention?  Usually, a refreshed Fragment is displaying up-to-date data.